# How bone of broken toe can be straightened without surgery?

Tags: surgery, broken-bones, self-healing-repairing, toe

I am reading this [article](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/patientinstructions/000520.htm)
about broken toe:

> If your toe is crooked after the injury, the bone may be out of place
>   and need to be straightened in order to heal properly.  This may be
>   done either with or **without surgery**.

It is the broken, I think it really needs surgery. Then why does this article
shows may not needed?

Comment: Most bone fractures don't require surgery. I don't know why you think they would.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking from experience: Depending on the type and severity of the break, if the bone has not yet healed in place, you can potentially tape the toe in such a way to keep it straight while the bone heals. Because it is difficult to stay off of your feet for several weeks to allow the bone to be stable, a boot is sometimes recommended.

Which toe it is also matters with regard to treatment. The big toe is responsible for 50% of the utility of all of your toes (source: my orthopedist).  The other 4 toes share the remaining 50%. So, if it is a smaller toe that is broken, a loss in functionality is not quite as problematic.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background.  Your orthopaedist does not count. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].